# PHP : dropdown list

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I have a problem for dropdown. I manually added the item in dropdown.. So Then.

My problem is:
the items inside of the dropwdown for firts and second page are:
Number 1 and
Number 2

The I choose "Number 1" in the first page then proceed in the page 2.
How can I removed the duplicate copy of "Number 1" in the second page for dropdown.?

Here's my code in page 1:

```
   <select id="duration"name="duration">
            <option value="15 s" >15 s</option>
            <option value="20 s" >20 s</option>
            </select><br/>
```

then second page:

```
<?php
$get_duration= $_POST['duration'];
?>

    <select name="select" >
                <option value="<?php echo $get_duration; ?>"><?php echo $get_duration; ?></option>
                <option value="15 s">15 s</option>
                <option value="20 s">20 s</option>
                </select><br/>
```

Thanks!.

Comment: This question is very hard to understand, please edit this so that we can help you better

Comment: where are  "Number 1" and "Number 2" ??

Comment: Sorry for the question. I already edited it.. Can you already understand my question?

Comment: @PhilistyneBrigidBellisima you have written `My problem is: the items inside of the dropwdown for firts and second page are: Number 1 and Number 2`  but where are those number (Number 1 and Number 2) ?

Comment: @swapnesh. the number 1 number 2 are inside in the dropdown

Comment: @RakeshShetty inside of the dropdown in first and second page.

Comment: you can use multiple if else condition to do this

Answer (score 0):

you should think (or read) about what is good practice to handle user choises ... the way you go is not the right one ...

to your problem ... so solve it:

```
<?php
    $get_duration= $_POST['duration'];
?>
   <select name="select" >
     <option value="15 s" <?php if($get_duration=='15 s') echo "selected"?> >15 s</option>
     <option value="20 s" <?php if($get_duration=='20 s') echo "selected"?> >20 s</option>
   </select><br/>
```

Comment: sorry...I'm just little confused on how I can explain it. but then thank you for helping me and understanding my question. :)

Answer (score 0):

If values of both droppdowns are the same, then you don't need to do this:

```
 <option value="<?php echo $get_duration; ?>"><?php echo $get_duration; ?></option>
```

because it will always already be there. I guess you want it to be selected, so you could simply do something like this for every `option` tag

```
<option value="15 s" <?php if($get_duration==='15 s') echo 'selected'; ?> >15 s</option>
```